# Call own PHP from JavaScript via Post throws 404

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, post

I have a WordPress Website. On one Page, when a button is clicked, I send a POST-request via JavaScript/jQuery which looks like this:

```
// callPhp.php via POST
    $.post("./wp-content/themes/avada/customdrink/callPhp.php",
        {
          a: 'callDoMagic',
          b: array
        },
        function(data){
          window.location.href=data;
        });
```

Even though the adressed file is in the named directory, I get an 404: File not Found error.

The domain points to the main wordpress directory.

Is this WordPress blocking my own PHP-File from executing? And if so, how can I open this php File through a POST-request?

Comment: Unless you're calling this from the site root homepage, then you'll want to drop the dot, so `post("./wp-content/` should probably be `post("/wp-content/`

Comment: Wordpress usually doesn't like you calling a PHP function in a theme directly.

Comment: @JeffPuckettII  sadly that doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: @Forbs you seem to be right. Acutually it does work on my localhost, so I guess this is the webserver that denies direct access to the file...